# Why mongodb ObjectId field gets a value of ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have collection in mongodb which looks like this:

```
Customers: 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e9...55"), "Adr" : ObjectId("52d5e53a0d4aff04a8a36c34") .. }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ea...e8"), "Adr" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000") ..}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ea...e8"), "Adr" : ObjectId("23423...5675") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ea...e8"), "Adr" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000") ..}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ea...e8"), "Adr" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000") ..}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ea...e8"), "Adr" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000") ..}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ea...e8"), "Adr" : ObjectId("34545...7677") ..}
```

**Upon creation I don't want to see Adr field in the customer doc as I never set it in my Customer constructor.**

As you can see Adr field stores the ObjectId of an Address doc from Adresses collection.
If I need to find the details of address for a given document, I can use the adrfield, get the id and then query the address collection.

This is my problem (or concerns):
When a new customers is added it doesn't have an address. Addresses are added later.
I want the adrfield to be null or empty upon creation of a new customer.
but I get ObjectId("000000000000000000000000") instead

I also need to create an index on address field, won't it create any problem if I have tons of customers with adr=ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")?

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
public class Customer
    {
        //code removed for simplicity

        public Customer()
        {
            Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();            

            //both of these works
            Name = null;
            Phone = string.Empty;

            //Doesn't work & creates Adr field w/  ObjectId("000..000") instead of null
            //cannot convert null to MongoDb.Bson.ObjectId because it is non-nullable value type
            //Adr = null;
        }

        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        //I added BsonIgnoreIfNull & didn't assign anything to Adr field in the constructor
        //But I keep getting a value of ObjectId("000000000000000000000000") in the Adr field
        [BsonElement("Adr"), BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public ObjectId Adr{ get; set; }    
}

public class Address
{
    public Address()
        {
            Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();            

            Street = null;
            City = null;
            State = null;
            Country = null;
        }

        //STORED IN THE ADR FIELD OF THE Customers collection above
        //DUE TO SOME SPECIFIC REASON I NEED SEPARATE COLLECTION FOR ADDRESS not embedding
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Street")]
        public string Street {get; set;}

        [BsonElement("City")]
        public string City {get; set;}

        [BsonElement("State"), BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public string State {get; set;}


        [BsonElement("Country")]
        public string Country {get; set;}    
}


Here is my MVC controller where I insert a new customer:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCustomer(string Name, string Phone){

   //code removed for simplicity

   Customer cust = new Customer();
   cust.Name = name;
   cust.Phone = phone;

   CustomerService svc = new CustomerService();
   svc.InsertCustomer(cust);

   return Result();
}
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Ahhh your model is wrong. They are not Foreign Keys in mongodb.

Comment: Edit your post and include more of your code. The problem is likely in the things you are masking. Be pre-warned, answers on this are going to tell you you're doing it wrong and you should be embedding

Comment: I think the relevant code to share (or check) is where you are creating the Customer document. You should be setting the `adr` field to `null` and adding it to the Customer document when the Address is created. Normally when you create a `BsonDocument` [the null fields are ignored](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#add-methods); in your case it seems like the Address reference is always set. The bogus zeroed ObjectIDs shouldn't cause an issue with indexing, but they are likely to complicate your application logic because you have a special case of invalid data.

Comment: Try adding the attribute `[BsonIgnoreIfNull]` to the `adr` field on the customer class.

Answer (score 0):

You really haven't posted enough of your code for anyone to specifically answer your question. Pseudo-code and Skeletons may be fine when that representation is not where the actual problem is, but in this case you clearly have something writing back that is causing the problem and you are not showing it.

That said what you are trying to do here is almost certainly what you do not want. You seem to be trying to follow a relational pattern saying that "I have a bunch of Address information over here in this other collection, and I just want to keep a reference to the one I want in this document."

Now in some cases that may be just fine, but address information seems trivial and should really be embedded as a sub-document in the main document. So you should very likely be looking at embedding and start losing your relational train of thought.

Even in the relational world, a real case example is a customer adress on an order. It makes no sense to reference an id for an address on an order as people change addresses all the time. And keeping an address record for someones old address is overkill. Though I have seen it done otherwise (and plenty) best practice is to just store the address information in the document.

MongoDB docs on their site has some really good reading on [Data Modelling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/). I suggest you take the time to have a good look at it. Worthwhile stuff :)

Comment: It all depends what vertical the software is intended for and whether addresses should be stored separately. The original question mentions knowledge of how the data is stored and the technical implementation.

Comment: @WiredPrairie sorry dude, I know you've built up a rep and I do like a lot of your answers but as general modeling this approach sucks and people need to be told so. I stated that I have seen this in relational and have ($gladly taken $work to fix it to my benefit) That said, I would **like** to promote future efforts to do better than what I have encountered before.

Comment: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/07/ravendb-what-am-i-persisting-what-am-i-querying-part-2/ This is for RavenDB but same same applies to MondoDB IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Adding a BsonIgnore solves my issue.
Thanks everyone for you valuable input